# Django model-field-choices became fields in table and cause not-null error

Tags: django, django-models, multi-select

The choices of a multiselectfield seem to have become fields in my table. I cannot give them a value, but I get an error that they violate the non-null constaint.
(I anonimised some of the code)

My model.py

```
class Plate(models.Model):
    Other irrelevant model fields here
    ------------------------


    PR_MDPH = 'PR-variable1'
    PR_MDM = 'PR-variable2'
    PR_AL = 'PR-variable3'
    PR_LE = 'PR-variable4'
    PR_FB = 'PR-variable5'
    PR_DB = 'PR-variable6'
    PR_DFR = 'PR-variable7'
    PR_BDG = 'PR-variable8'
    PR_ME = 'PR-variable9'
    PR_NO = 'None'

    DEFECT_PR_CHOICES = (
        (PR_MDPH, 'PR-variable1'),
        (PR_MDM, 'PR-variable2'),
        (PR_AL, 'PR-variable3'),
        (PR_LE, 'PR-variable4'),
        (PR_FB, 'PR-variable5'),
        (PR_DB, 'PR-variable6'),
        (PR_DFR, 'PR-variable7'),
        (PR_BDG, 'PR-variable8'),
        (PR_ME, 'PR-variable9'),
        (PR_NO, 'None'),
    )

    AR_MDPH = 'AR-variable1'
    AR_MDM = 'AR-variable2'
    AR_AL = 'AR-variable3'
    AR_LE = 'AR-variable4'
    AR_FB = 'AR-variable5'
    AR_DB = 'AR-variable6'
    AR_DFR = 'AR-variable7'
    AR_BDG = 'AR-variable8'
    AR_ME = 'AR-variable9'
    AR_BO = 'AR-variable10'
    AR_GL = 'AR-variable11'
    AR_BW = 'AR-variable12'
    AR_NO = 'None'

    DEFECT_AR_CHOICES = (
        (AR_MDPH, 'AR-variable1'),
        (AR_MDM, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_AL, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_LE, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_FB, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_DB, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_DFR, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_BDG, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_ME, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_BO, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_GL, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_BW, 'AR-variable'),
        (AR_NO, 'None'),
    )

    PR_defect = MultiSelectField(choices=DEFECT_PR_CHOICES, default=PR_NO)
    AR_defect = MultiSelectField(choices=DEFECT_AR_CHOICES, default=AR_NO)
```

When I look in my local pgAdmin database, I now have the following:

```
    randomField text blabla
    moreFields boolean NOT NULL

    "AR_defect" character varying(29) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "PR_defect" character varying(19) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "PR_NO" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_AL" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_BDG" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_BO" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_BW" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_DB" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_DFR" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_FB" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_GL" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_LE" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_MDM" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_MDPH" boolean NOT NULL,
    "AR_ME" boolean NOT NULL,
    "PR_AL" boolean NOT NULL,
    "PR_BDG" boolean NOT NULL,
    "PR_DB" boolean NOT NULL,
    "PR_DFR" boolean NOT NULL,
    "PR_FB" boolean NOT NULL,
    "PR_LE" boolean NOT NULL,
   "PR_MDM" boolean NOT NULL,
    "PR_MDPH" boolean NOT NULL,
    "PR_ME" boolean NOT NULL,
```

This does not happen with choices for other model fields. Just for these model fields where I used MultiSelectField
The problem that arises now, is that when I try to create a new plate model, the database expects a value for above 'variables', which are actually just choices.

The error that I get:

```
IntegrityError at class x
null value in column "PR_NO" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (Values for other variables here, None, PR_NO, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
```

I cannot provide a values, as they are values themselves and not fields.
I tried adding a new model object via the designated route in my code/website, which throws this error. I also tried adding a new model object via the admin panel, which gives me the same error.

The fields in the admin panel:
[image: Part of the Django Admin panel]

Did I do something wrong, or is this perhaps a bug?

All in all, it seems like somehow, due to a bug or my own inexperience, I created columns in the database for fields that are actually values in a choice field. Now I assume I have to somehow delete these columns?

I hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction.